# what data type should i use for printing a number like 64.432785439?

Tags: c

**what data type i need to use and what %?**
**i tried lots of them and i printed only 0 or 0.00000**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ab;
    int ac;
    int bc;
    printf("introdu valoarea laturii AB:\n");
    scanf("%d", &ab);
    printf("introdu valoarea laturii BC:\n");
    scanf("%d", &bc);
    printf("introdu valoarea laturii AC:\n");
    scanf("%d", &ac);
    int per= (bc+ac+ab)/2;
    unsigned int x= sqrt(per*(per - ab)*(per-bc)*(per-ac));

    printf("aria triunghiului este: %x", x);//printarea ariei triunghiului
}
```

Comment: at the "x" print is the question

Comment: But you don't even *have* a number like 64.432785439.

Comment: like it not that number,but with a lot of decimals

Comment: @AlexSturza -- to get help with a problem like this, you should remove the `scanfs` from the code and set `ab`, `bc`, and `ac` to fixed values.  Either that, or you need to tell people what you're typing in for `ab`, `bc`, and `ac`.  Without that information, other people can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a double like this:

```
double per= (bc+ac+ab)/2.0;
double x= sqrt(per*(per - ab)*(per-bc)*(per-ac));

printf("aria triunghiului este: %lf", x);
```

**EDIT:-**

If you are not passing the int value as the side of your triangle then you need to change the datatype of your input variables as well

```
double ab = 0.0;
double ac = 0.0;
double bc = 0.0;
```

**[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/tjDcAD)**

Comment: still 0.0000 as result

Comment: @AlexSturza:- Updated my answer. Please check now.

Comment: @AlexSturza:- What is the value of ab,bc,ac which you are passing?

Comment: @AlexSturza:- Then what you are getting is correct. The area of triangle with `4,5,2` as the sides is **3.79967**. Check this http://www.handymath.com/cgi-bin/irregangle12.cgi

Comment: check the per result with the 4,5,2 values it will be 4158,and radical from 4158 is ≈64.48255578061404

Comment: @AlexSturza:- I am not getting what you are trying to achieve. As per your program you are trying to get the area of triangle and the result which you are getting is correct as per the given input. What is the confusion?

Comment: per is the perimeter of a triangle,and i get the area value with Heron's method

Comment: @AlexSturza - The perimeter of the triangle is 5+4+2 = 11.  But Heron's method uses the **perimeter divided by 2** which is 5.5. So the calculation is `sqrt(5.5 * 1.5 * 0.5 * 3.5)`.  Also, if you draw the triangle on a piece of graph paper, you can see that the area can't possibly be 64, even a 5x4 rectangle only has a area of 20.

Comment: @AlexSturza:- But this was really disappointing to see that this was not an accepted answer! :( Anyways happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("aria triunghiului este: aria %.9f", x);
```

This will print a float type with nine decimal places, but you'll need a `float` type and `x` in your case is an `unsigned int`.

Change your last lines to:

```
float per= (bc+ac+ab)/2.0f;
double x= sqrt(per*(per - ab)*(per-bc)*(per-ac)));
printf("aria triunghiului este: aria %.9lf", x);
```

Comment: 0.0000 as the result in printf

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to have *all* your variables declared as `double`.

```
double ab=0.0, ac=0.0, bc=0.0, x=0.0;
```

<sup>I think that initializing variables is a good habit. You could initialize them with `NAN` from `<math.h>` ...</sup>

Read them with e.g.

```
if (scanf("%f", &ab)<=0) 
    { perror("failed ab input"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Print them using `%g` or `%.6f` etc.

You absolutely need to read [the floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) i.e. *What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*

You should also read about every standard function you are using, in particular about [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) and [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) etc.

You should compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`). Learn right now about it!

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of your example,
for printing a fixed point value in c you should use %f, like:

```
double someDoubleVar=64.123132123;
printf("%f",someDoubleVar);
```

you can control the number of digits after the point by doing:

```
double someDoubleVar=64.123132123;
printf("%.3f",someDoubleVar);
```

(copy it and you will see the output will be 64.123).

In your program:

```
double per= (bc+ac+ab)/2.0;
double x= sqrt(per*(per - ab)*(per-bc)*(per-ac));
printf("aria triunghiului este: %lf", x);
```

will probably do the job.
you can consider useing only double variables if so comment.